# AutoMapper infinity Loop In MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper, stack-overflow

I'm getting a stack overflow exception in my mvc project...

I Call MapInitialize.Initialize in Global.asax file

this is MapInitialize class...

```
using AutoMapper;
using Model1 = Project.BusinessLogic.Model;
using Model2 = Project.DataAccess.Model;

namespace Project.BusinessLogic
{
    public static class MapInitialize
    {
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Model1.table, Model2.table>();
        }
    }
}
```

this is Model1.table tables fields with partial class

```
    namespace Project.BusinessLogic
    {
        public partial class table
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string field1{ get; set; }
            public string field2 { get; set; }
            public string field3{ get; set; }

            public virtual table2 table2 { get; set; }
        }
    }


    using Model = Project.DataAccess.Model;
    namespace Project.BusinessLogic
    {        
        public partial class table
        {
             public static implicit operator Model.table(table model)
             {
                 if (model == null) return null;
                 return Mapper.Map<table, Model.table>(model);
             }

             public static implicit operator table(Model.table model)
             {
                 if (model == null) return null;
                 return Mapper.Map<Model.table, table>(model);
             }
         }
     }
```

and I getting exception...

```
 public Result<Model.table> Createtable(Model.table model)
{
    var result = new Result<Model.table>();
    try
    {
        model.field1 = "foo";
        model.field2 = "foo2";
        var res = Ctx.table.Add(model);
        Ctx.SaveChanges();
        result.Value = res; ***// here is infinity loop exception*** 
        result.Success = result.Value != null;
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Console.Log(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not always a good idea to be using casting operators as it makes it very difficult to see what code is being executed. When you do use them, it's a good idea not to have two-way `implicit` cast operators. Try and make one of them `explicit`. That should reduce the chance of an infinite loop.

That being said, I think in your case it would be far clearer to someone else reading the code if you were to add a `Mapper.Map` call explicitly instead of relying on cast operators.